# Re-Entrant or Thread Safe

Tags: multithreading, sockets

I have implemented this code for Hanlding Multiple clients.I have a Doubt on this.Is this function is a re-entrant function?

```
void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    //Get the socket descriptor
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int read_size;
    char *message , client_message[2000];

    //Send some messages to the client
    message = "Greetings! I am your connection handler\n";
    write(sock , message , strlen(message));

    message = "Now type something and i shall repeat what you type \n";
    write(sock , message , strlen(message));

    //Receive a message from client
    while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
    {
        //Send the message back to client
        write(sock , client_message , strlen(client_message));
    }

    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv failed");
    }

    //Free the socket pointer
    free(socket_desc);

    return 0;
}
```

If it  handles multiple clients means how it syncronize?

I call this function using pthread_create in main function.

Thanks.

Comment: I can only see here unsynchronized `stdout` using.

Comment: I can't understand.can you please elobarate?

Comment: Your question is about thread safety. Lines `puts("Client disconnected"); fflush(stdout); perror("recv failed");` are not thread safe because they use the same output streams from different threads without synchronization. All other code uses local resources and therefore, thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for the information.But i am asking about connection_handler function.Is it re-entrant?
We can close the stdout and get those output using file read/write also.

Comment: using `perror` and writing to the same output stream from multiple threads is not thread-safe. The rest of the function is thread-safe.

Comment: `function is called reentrant if it can be interrupted in the middle of its execution and then safely called again.` This function cannot be interrupted and called again in the same thread. So, reentrancy program just doesn't exist here.

Comment: I would be surprised if stdout() etc. doesn't have an internal lock, (as long as multithreaded versions of the libs have been linked, which is often the default).

Comment: Suppose if the context switch occur between the read and write means is it possible to overwrite one thread data to another thread?